# Find, convert and replace some text but keep remaining text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following text file:

```
8/1 text1 1/5 text2 9/2
4/9 text1 3/1 text2 9/2
```

I would like to convert all of the fractions to be decimals (odds), but maintain the format and the unconverted text, so after conversion:

```
9.0 text1 1.2 text2 5.5
1.44 text1 4.0 text2 5.5
```

I can convert the fractions to decimals using the code below, but I can't figure out how to maintain the format and unconverted text:

```py
import os
import re
from fractions import Fraction
import fileinput
import sys

def main():
    text = open('text.txt').read()
    regex = re.findall("\d/\d", text)
    for dec_odd in regex:
        dec_odd = Fraction(dec_odd)
        dec_odd = float(dec_odd)
        dec_odd = dec_odd +1
        print(dec_odd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried to loop through each line and convert one by one but again struggling to only convert the fraction and not the full line (and the mixing up of types):

```
    for line in fileinput.input("text.txt", inplace = 1):
        frac_odd = re.search("\d/\d", line)
        dec_odd = Fraction(frac_odd)
        dec_odd = float(dec_odd)
        print(line.replace(frac_odd, dec_odd))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were on the right track but `re.search()` doesn't return a `str`, it returns a *match object* from which you need to extract the `str` you want:

```
import re
from fractions import Fraction

text = open('text.txt').read()

fraction = re.search(r"\d+/\d+", text)

while fraction:
    string = fraction.group(0)
    decimal = format(1.0 + float(Fraction(string)), '.3')
    text = text.replace(string, decimal)
    fraction = re.search(r"\d+/\d+", text)

print(text, end='')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
9.0 text1 1.2 text2 5.5
1.44 text1 4.0 text2 5.5
%
```

Comment: Thank you, such a simple way to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.sub()`:

```
import re

data = '''8/1 text1 1/5 text2 9/2
4/9 text1 3/1 text2 9/2'''

def format_fraction(a, b):
    s = '{:.3g}'.format(float(a) / float(b) + 1)
    if '.' not in s:
        return s + '.0'
    return s

s = re.sub(r'\b(\d+)/(\d+)\b', lambda g: format_fraction(g.group(1), g.group(2)) , data)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
9.0 text1 1.2 text2 5.5
1.44 text1 4.0 text2 5.5
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great but I didn't find it as easy to understand as @cdlane's answer